# MySQLdb - Error with simple statement

Tags: python, mysql, insert, mysql-python

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("XXXXXXXX","root", "XXXXXX", database)
cursor = db.cursor() 
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO media_files (ID, DATA) VALUES ("test", "test")')
cursor.execute("commit")
```

This statement errors and I cannot seem to figure out why. Any thoughts? The table media_files btw only has the two columns, ID and DATA each of which are VARCHAR(255)

Thanks
Trent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'INSERT INTO media_files (ID, DATA) VALUES ("test", "test")'
```

Using the parentheses will fix the problem. You were inserting one piece of data but provided 2 fields.